# Windows Forms MouseEnter not firing after control moved

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, mouseenter

I want to color the `BackColor` property of a `PictureBox` when the mouse enters it.

I turn the `BackColor` into Yellow when then `MouseEnter` event fires, and I reset to transparent in `MouseLeave`.

Then when I click on a `PictureBox`, I change its position, so I also have a `Move` event which resets it in transparent.

The problem is, once I moved it, I need to enter the `PictureBox` twice with the mouse to fire the MouseEnter event!

It's a very graphical problem, so I uploaded a little [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pg_u0FYAKnc&feature=youtu.be) to show you what's happening, it surely will explain my problem better than I do.

I tried another way, changing the color not in `MouseEnter` but in `MouseHover`. In this case, it works well, except that I have a 500ms delay before firing the Move event, which is obviously not what I want.

I have no viable solution right now.

For the code, it's very simple, for the moment I have :

```
private void pictureBoxMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // I move the PictureBox here
}
 
private void pictureBoxMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as PictureBox).BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
 
private void pictureBoxMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as PictureBox).BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
}
 
private void pictureBoxMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as PictureBox).BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

In the Designer.cs, my events for each PictureBox are like :

```
this.pictureBox2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseDown);
this.pictureBox2.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseEnter);
this.pictureBox2.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseLeave);
this.pictureBox2.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseUp);
this.pictureBox2.Move += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBoxMove);
```

EDIT : To answer my question, this is the code I use now : (comments are in french)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EmoTEDTherapeute;

namespace ControlSceneImage {

    public class SceneImage : PictureBox {

        public static readonly int defaultWidth = 100;
        public static readonly int defaultHeight = 100;

        static readonly int activePbPosY; // Position en Y des scènes actives

        static readonly Dictionary<string, Point> scenesPos = null; // Invariant, stocke la position initiale des PictureBox
        static readonly List<Point>[] activeScenesPos = null; // Invariant, stocke les positions des PictureBox en fonction du nombre de scènes actives

        static List<SceneImage> activeScenes = null;

        const int maxActiveScenes = 5;
        const int ecart = 80;
        const int decalage = 15;
        const int panelScenesWidth = 909;
        const int panelScenesHeight = 154;
        const int panelScenesLocationX = 35;
        const int panelScenesLocationY = 36;

        bool isActive;

        static SceneImage() {
            // Constructeur initialisant tous les membres statiques, n'est appelé qu'une seule fois, avant tout le reste
            activePbPosY = (panelScenesLocationY + panelScenesHeight - (int)(0.6 * defaultHeight)) / 2;
            scenesPos = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
            activeScenesPos = new List<Point>[maxActiveScenes];
            for (int i = 0; i < maxActiveScenes; i++) {
                activeScenesPos[i] = CalcActiveScenesPos(i+1);
            }
            activeScenes = new List<SceneImage>();
        }

        public SceneImage() {
            MouseEnter += new EventHandler(OnMouseEnter);
            MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseDown);
            MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseUp);
            MouseLeave += new EventHandler(OnMouseLeave);
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Size = new Size(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            isActive = false;
        }

        private static List<Point> CalcActiveScenesPos(int nbActiveScenes) {
            List<Point> ret = new List<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nbActiveScenes; i++) {
                ret.Add(new Point((panelScenesLocationX + panelScenesWidth + ecart) / 2 + (int)((ecart + defaultWidth) * (i - nbActiveScenes / 2.0)) + decalage, activePbPosY));
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private void UpdateScenesPos() {
            for(int i = 0; i < activeScenes.Count; i++) {
                activeScenes[i].Location = activeScenesPos[activeScenes.Count - 1][i];
            }
        }

        private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }

        private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }

        private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (!scenesPos.ContainsKey(Name)) {
                // Si ce n'est pas déjà fait, on stocke la position initiale de notre PictureBox
                scenesPos.Add(Name, Location);
                // Et on crée un Panel vide sous elle
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                panel.Location = Location;
                panel.Size = Size;
                panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                // On ajoute notre panel à notre form
                Form1.AddInSeance(panel);
            }
            if (!isActive) {
                activeScenes.Add(this);
            } else {
                Location = scenesPos[Name];
                activeScenes.Remove(this);
            }
            isActive = !isActive;
            UpdateScenesPos();
        }

        private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the same method as before, and for an unknown reason, now it works.
Thanks to all of you for helping me :)

Comment: I wrote a "hello everyone" on top of my message but it seems it's been cut when I post for some odd reason, even when I edited it, so don't be rude :)

Comment: can you please provide more code to show which events you assigned to your handlers?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with some focus parts.

Comment: @Falco Alexander I edited my first post but I don't know if I understood you correctly !

Comment: What is the code you use to move the control?

Comment: Is the event `MouseLeave` raised when the control is moved?

Comment: @codroipo The code I use to move the control is like pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y)... Perhaps not the best way to do it ?
And MouseLeave isn't raised when I move my control. I tried to raise it manually in the Move event, or right after changing the location of the PictureBox, but both didn't work.

Comment: @user3623965 "Hello", etc. are [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) as they clutter things up; many salutations are [automatically removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/141629). Don't worry, no one thinks you're being impolite :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you relocate the `PictureBox`, it will not receive the mouse leave event. Maybe you have already noticed that, that's why you set the `BackColor` in the `Move` event, too.

After you moved the control, it will not receive a second `MouseEnter` when you hover it again, only after you moved the mouse off and on again.

Try to send a mouse leave event manually (I haven't tested it):

```
private const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void pictureBoxMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // move the PictureBox...

    SendMessage(((PictureBox)sender).Handle, WM_MOUSELEAVE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I noticed MouseLeave was not raised and that's why I used Move event ;)
Thanks for this, I tried but it didn't change anything... But we're maybe close to the solution !

Comment: Maybe you should use it with the `TrackMouseEvent`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646265%28VS.85%29.aspx
This is a one shot event, so it needs to be called again after an event is handled in order to receive future events. See the bottom of the linked page for the C# usage.

Comment: I'm searching and searching but can't get it working... The code given in the bottom of the page gives me errors that I don't understand, and the solution seems super-heavy for a little problem like mine

Answer (score 1):

I will avoid to move the `PictureBox`. Clearly your bug come from that.

When you move the component, the mouse is no more in it but it status is not updated.

You can swim deep in [the windows form reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) or you can just says you have **N** small preview (the pictures on the bottom line) and one big preview (the upper one).

Create N+1 picture box and don't change it. Just change their [image property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When a small preview is clicked, switch it's image property with the big preview.

Also, a good [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is recommended.

Comment: Yes, I will try that and I come back when I made it work, thanks !